# Android layout folder organization

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and I currently have about 8 layout xml files in the `layout` folder.  The need for organizing this folder is increasing with each additional layout resource file. However, when I create a folder inside of the layout folder and move a resource to it via the refactor operation, it breaks my project.

For example, my resource is being refernced here:

```
setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

After moving the **login.xml** file to a newly created folder called `"test"`, it breaks my build.

If I update the reference to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.test.login);
```

It still doesn't compile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Answer (score 11):

Sub folders in resources is not currently supported. I think everyone who read this should put a star on the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018&q=sub%20folder%20res&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Comment: Now, according to the [article](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018#c64) it appears that if you use the Gradle build system you **can** have sub directories. However, Google will **not** be implementing this for other build systems (e.g. Ant, etc.). Relevant Comment: "Marking this as released. This is largely possible in the Gradle build system as it exists today, and we won't be implementing this for other build systems"

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the naming convention 
You cannot create a folder inside a layout.
if you want to create a folder, create inside a res folder.
ex:-  layout-large,layout-small etc