# Folders in /res in android project

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can The Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

How to organize graphics/java/xml file in folders in android project in eclipse?
I mean - should I (to store graphics) create folder in my 'drawable-mdpi' or as a separated folder?

I tried making folder in drawable and calling file by:

```
@drawable/photo/fileName
```

also tried making separate folder in /res, and call by:

```
@photo/fileName
```

but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I (to store graphics) create folder in my 'drawable-mdpi' or as a separated folder?

Sadly, you cannot create your own file structure in the `/res` folder... You must use the [existing folder structure](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html), like `/res/drawable-mdpi` and use `R.drawable.xxx`.

You can read about this "bug" here: [Android layout folder organization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4905143/1267661) or read the *brief* explanation straight from a lead Android programmer: [Can The Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077357/1267661).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need/can't use a separate folder. Just put in each drawable folder and access with `@drawable/filename` with no extension

Comment: So there is no way to somehow organize it (apart from alphabetic sorting files)? Seems to me like an absurd.

Comment: It does seem nuts but, no, you can't add separate folders to the `res` folder :(